# Пожалуйста, помогите исправить "уравнение"

Tags: php

Функция

```
if (!isset($listQueryVideoHit))
$listQueryVideoHit = 0;

elseif($listQueryVideoHit === 5)
$listQueryVideoHit = 0;
```

Сейчас `".(++$listQueryVideoHit)."` выведет 
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5

Нужно 
1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2
3,3,3,3,3
4,4,4,4,4
5,5,5,5,5

Попробовал методом тыка, не получилось :(
Спасибо!

```
protected function getcates($nom){
$part = "snippet";
foreach ($wares as $item)
{
$itemtitle = $item->title;
$arr1 = array('XXX');
$arr2 = array('');
$itemtitle=str_replace($arr1, $arr2, $item->title);
$item->title=str_replace($arr1, $arr2, $item->title);
$itemtitle = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}0-9 \!]/iu', ' ', $itemtitle);
$block = "";
$this->url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=";
$data = $this->http(TRUE);
foreach ($data->items as $yt) {


if (!isset($listQueryVideoHit))
    $listQueryVideoHit = 0;

elseif($listQueryVideoHit === 5)
$listQueryVideoHit = 0;


$block .= "
<!-- Begin Post -->
<article class=\"post-format-".(++$listQueryVideoHit).">
....................
</article>
<!-- End Post -->
";
}
if(!empty($block)){
$html .= '1'.$block.'2';
}
}
}
return $html;
}
```

Comment: Полный код покажите с циклом в котором всё это происходит

Comment: добавил код в вопрос

Comment: Омг, я узнаю́ это)

Comment: Ага, шаблон пришлось сменить, вот доделываю )

Comment: Пожалуйста, не удаляйте код. Это же существенная часть вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынесите инкремент из внутреннего цикла:

```
if (!isset($listQueryVideoHit) || $listQueryVideoHit === 5) $listQueryVideoHit = 0;
$listQueryVideoHit++;
foreach ($data->items as $yt) {
 // <article class=\"post-format-".($listQueryVideoHit).">
}
```

Comment: vp_arth, спасибо! Работает   :)